# How do turn this code into using gsl::at without causing an "internal compilation error"?

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis

Code:

```
if (pListWeeksToPrint != nullptr && !(*pListWeeksToPrint)[iDate])
    continue;
```

Warning:

> Warning   C26446  Prefer to use gsl::at() instead of unchecked subscript operator (bounds.4).

I tried:

```
if (pListWeeksToPrint != nullptr && !gsl::at(*pListWeeksToPrint, iDate))
```

I get:

> fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.

`pListWeeksToPrint` is a parameter to my function: `std::vector<bool> *pListWeeksToPrint`

It is a simple list of `bool`s. I pass a pointer to the vector because the function is also used when there is no list (no the vector is null). But when it is not null I have to do the check.

I have clearly scuppered up tweaking the code. If I revert back to my former code it compiles.

Comment: Think I sorted it. Will add a answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why the compiler had an internal failure but I was able to simplify my code:

`if (pListWeeksToPrint != nullptr && !pListWeeksToPrint->at(iDate))`

That did the trick!